# How do you have a Discord bot remove a user reaction to a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using an `@client.event` and using `async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):` to read Discord reaction events. I need to be able to delete a user reaction when they fail one of the flags in my code. I saw in the documentation that there is `await remove(user)` but I don't think I'm using it right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either [`Message.remove_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.remove_reaction) or [`Reaction.remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.remove).

A [Reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction) object represents a specific emoji reaction to a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message), so if the Reaction object you have is not for the emoji reaction that you want to remove, using `Reaction.remove` will attempt to remove the wrong emoji reaction.

Comment: When i try to use the msg id I get from the on_raw_reaction_add payload, it tells me that "int" has no attribute "remove_reaction" and when I use "Message" it tells me that Message isn't defined which I get, here is the code which i will simplify

'@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload)
    .
    .
    .
elif banned == 1:
    await Message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji.name , payload.user_id)'

Comment: Message IDs are integers, not [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) objects, so of course they won't have `remove_reaction` methods. You need to get an instance of `discord.Message` and define it as `Message`, if that's what you want to call it. You can do so with the message ID, e.g. via [`TextChannel.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message). In the future, you should provide all the relevant code and the full traceback when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out as you commented that, also im getting an error where its saying that my int object has no attribute id, which is the payload.user_id, is there another way to grab the user id?

Comment: Again, IDs are integers. That includes user IDs as well. You already have the user ID. That's what [`RawReactionActionEvent.user_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.user_id) is..

Comment: As [the documentation for `Message.remove_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.remove_reaction) says, the `member` that's passed must represent a member and meet the [`Snowflake`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Snowflake) ABC. This is not the case for an integer representing the ID of a user.

Comment: How would I go about getting the `member` then?

Comment: nvm i figured it out, I needed to use `guild.fetch_members(payload.user_id)`, thx so much for the help and your time!

Comment: You should take a look at the [*How do I get a specific model?* section of the FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model). Since you're only retrieving one [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object, there's no reason to use [`Guild.fetch_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members) rather than [`Guild.fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member).

Comment: In fact, there's no reason to use an HTTP/API request at all here, unless you've set `fetch_offline_members` to `False` when initializing your [Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client), as the member will be in the user cache and in [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members), and thus retrievable simply with [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member).