# Disable a discord bot in DM with client.event

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to disable people using my discord bot in DMs, I know how to do with commands but can't figure it out when its @client.event.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!flip '):
        keyword = message.content.split('!flip ')[1]
        await start(keyword, message.channel)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you have a Discord bot remove a user reaction to a message in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512455/how-do-you-have-a-discord-bot-remove-a-user-reaction-to-a-message-in-discord-py)

Comment: No looks like a different issue altogether