# using a bot to remove a specific user's reaction on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a small 2-player game for my discord bot, And part of what the bot does is to react to its own message with some emojis as options

I want the bot to remove the user's reaction as soon as they react with the emoji, but `message.reaction.remove` or `message.remove_reaction` do not seem to work for me, here's some example code in case this was not clear:

```
import numpy as np
import discord

player1 = message.author #the user who starts the game with a command
player2 = message.mentions[0] #the first user who gets mentioned in the command

nums = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣"]

The_Board = await message.channel.send(#The message that the bot will react to with nums)

while not game_over:
try:
    reaction, confirmation = await client.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check)

turn = 0

if turn == 0:
    Reaction_Turn = player1
elif turn == 1:
    Reaction_Turn = player2


if Reaction_Turn == player1 and str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
    colnum = 0
elif Reaction_Turn == player1 and str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
    colnum = 1

#repetitive code for 7 emojis
#do stuff here

for i in nums:
    await message.remove_reaction(i,Reaction_Turn)
```

Comment: can you also include the libraries and modules you are using?

Comment: I edited-in the list of libraries I used for the game @anarchy

Comment: what is player1 and player2 supposed to be? what object?

Comment: does this answer you question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512455/how-do-you-have-a-discord-bot-remove-a-user-reaction-to-a-message-in-discord-py

Comment: @anarchy added the player1 and player2 objects to the post, I have tried the solution on the post you mentioned, but after the user reacts with an emoji, the bot doesn't remove the reactions, but doesn't give me an error either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I finally got the remove_reaction method working, if you want to use this method under `on_message`, try using `try/except` for the method:

```
try:
    message = The_Board
    user = Reaction_Turn
    for x in nums:
        await message.remove_reaction(x,user)
except:
    pass
```